# does google maps api block bot?

Tags: google-places-api, googlebot

When I check a URL in Google webmaster tool, I found this.

[image: Google webmaster tool]

I have added Google Places javascript API in my webpage , but the calls were blocked when it was through Google bot. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Click through the "robots.txt" link, and see what it says.

I think you'll see:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /maps/api/js?
Allow: /maps/api/js/DirectionsService.Route
Allow: /maps/api/js/DistanceMatrixService.GetDistanceMatrix
Allow: /maps/api/js/ElevationService.GetElevationForLine
Allow: /maps/api/js/GeocodeService.Search
Allow: /maps/api/js/KmlOverlayService.GetFeature
Allow: /maps/api/js/KmlOverlayService.GetOverlays
Allow: /maps/api/js/LayersService.GetFeature
Disallow: /
```

... which means that the `/maps-api-v3/...` paths you're trying are indeed disallowed.

Comment: is there any other way I can achieve this?